# INNER join doesn't work with PDO in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, odbc

I'm facing a very strange problem. I have a SQL Server query which is very simple and working fine in any environment. I ran it and it was fine, but in my PHP, code doesn't work for some reason, and it returns empty array:

```
function conexion() {

$username = 'blahblah';
$password = 'blahblah';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO ("odbc:SQL_FLOC", $username, $password);
    $sql = $pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT ent.id, pob.tmax from entradas AS ent INNER JOIN in_previsio_poblacio AS pob ON ent.id=pob.idpob");
    $sql->execute();

    $row = $sql->columnCount();
    print_r($row);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Conexión fallida', $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

}
```

i have changed `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT RIGHT OUTTER` and still get 0. Any idea?

**UPDATE SAMPLE DATA:**

this is the result i get by running the query in NAVICAT

**Result of query:**

[image]

**Enteradas:**

[image]

I cant share more than two picture, but I'm sure the table and query is just fine. The problem should be something about driver or something else.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: what happens when you run this without the `conexion()` function? ;-) this is a question btw. So, what *does* happen when you do? It works, right? variable scope ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- nothing the same 0

Comment: @AriaR. anything from http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ? plus, you will need to update your question with the schemas and example values.

Comment: @AriaR. add some sample data please

Comment: @Fred-ii- no error only empty array. the table is very big with more than 100 column i upload html export by Navi Cat

Comment: Just show sample data not all 100 cols u have

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i took an screen but i'm sure the query is fine because the same query works in navicat

Comment: by sample data we mean that post your entradas table and in_previsio_poblacio  table

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile they are very big tables more than 1 gig :(

Answer (score 0):

In case who had the same problem here is the way i fixed it. I don´t know what was the problem but i changed the PDO driver and it works now. I was using the odbc driver and then i changed it to sqlsvr:

`$pdo = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=FLOC\FLOC, 1473;Database=meteo", $username, $password);`